# Is the clause "I ever have" in the sentence "the best gift I ever have" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, grammaticality-in-context, conditionals

I am hesitant whether the sentence "the best gift that I ever have", is appropriate for expressing that the gift that will be given to me in the future (might happen or might not) will be the best gift that I ever have.

To date, I haven't got the gift yet, but if in the future I receive that gift, I will consider it as the best gift ever.

So which one is the best to say it?

1.The best gift I have ever had.

2.The best gift I ever have.

3.The best gift I will ever have.

Second question :
Is this sentence classified as conditional sentence? If so, what this thing is called in English conditional sentence?
Personally speaking, I just know that "ever" is only used for present perfect tense in several contexts of second or third conditional construction or, generally speaking, in the common/normal sentence.

So, what category does it belong to when we intend to write "ever" for future tense?

I hope you understand my questions. :)

Comment: "the best gift that I ever have" is ***not*** a "sentence" - it's a ***noun phrase***. Valid phrasings for which are *the best gift I [have] ever had* - with or without that auxiliary ***had***, which has no effect on the meaning (it's effectively a stylistic choice whether to include it). It might help you to consider the same text using the past tense verb ***received*** instead of ***had*** (where *that* instance of the verb "to have" is *not* an "auxiliary" - it's a full-blown verb with the meaning *obtained, got, acquired*). And optional ***ever*** here simply adds "emphasis".

Comment: Thank you for your corrections. Does it mean that my following instance "the best gift I ever have" is grammatically incorrect and makes no sense at all for the readers? Or is it still acceptable?

Comment: This will be the best gift ever.

Comment: If you may or may not get it - _That would be the best gift I could ever have_.

Comment: The construction *the best [noun] [subject] ever [verb]*, with *[verb]* as a ***present tense*** is relatively unusual, and doesn't really work in your context. It's possible to say something like *I often go to expensive restaurants, but **the best meal I ever have** is the "Soup of the day", because I can't afford anything better.* But there aren't many contexts where Present Tense *best I ever **have*** can be used, and yours isn't one of them.

Comment: I can't see any problem with "If I get that Rolls, Royce, it will be the best gift I ever have". - _The Best Meatballs You'll Ever Have_ (Recipes.com),

Comment: @Michael Harvey: Those are effectively ***Future*** Tense contexts. Even my example isn't the true "standard" Present Tense for something happening *at time of speaking* - it's a "continuous, habitual, timeless" usage (forced by ***ever***, without which it would indeed mean the best I have *right now)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you ❤️Another question that comes up in my mind is that, does the phrase "I have ever had" fit to the context of future tense as in my example? Because "the best gift I have ever had" refers to the gift that I have already received, & does not refer to the gift that I WILL receive.  How about the construction "the best gift I will ever have"? Does it sound more relevant to my initial intention that I write that phrase for the purpose of expressing future tense that the gift, which is presumably given or not, as the best give that I will ever receive?

Comment: Please ask again underneath my Answer if you still have things you don't understand

Comment: “This is the best gift ever.” is quite acceptable and avoids a lot of the issues you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that *the best gift [that] I [have] ever have* isn't a "sentence" - it's a "noun phrase" (within which the "head noun" is ***gift***). Also note that it's perfect okay to include or omit either/both the "relativiser" ***that*** and the "auxiliary verb" ***have***, and this has no effect on the meaning (it's *entirely* a stylistic choice).

BUT the second instance of ***have*** isn't an auxiliary. It's a normal verb usage, with the meaning *get, obtain, acquire, receive,...* So our choice is between...

> 1: *This is the best gift I ever **get***
> 2: *This is the best gift I ever **got***
> 3: *This is the best gift I **will** ever **get***

In all those examples, the optional word ***ever*** provides *emphasis* (drawing attention to the fact that I ***never*** *get* or *got* or *will get* any gift better than this on any occasions whatsoever).

---

In most contexts, Past Tense *(best I ever **had**)* is the correct choice (in which case you're not necessarily ruling out the possibility of getting an even better gift in the future). You're saying that *at no time in the past* did you ever have anything better.

But note that Present Tense *(best I ever **have**)* doesn't exactly refer to *present = now = time of speaking*. It's the "timeless" use of the verb form, implying "never at all" (in the Past, Present, OR Future). And that's probably not the intended meaning.

---

It's possible to be even *more* emphatic by using ***could*** instead of ***will*** for the "future" reference in #3 above...

> 4: *This is the best gift I **could** ever **get***
> (there never was and never could be a better gift)

...and it's *possible*, though a bit clunky, to use that form for the "Past up until Present" context...

> 5: *This is the best gift I **could** ever **have got***
> (no past or current gift is better, but feasibly there might be a better *future* gift)